# How to close a popup userControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to close a user control by a button click.
[UI](https://gyazo.com/38560599537bf9bd92c744be79e26fa9)

So the red user control needs to close when the button is clicked.
But with my code is closed the whole application.

This doesn't work:

`Window.GetWindow(this).Close();`

This also doesn't work:

`Window parentwin = Window.GetWindow(this);
            parentwin.Close();`

When I run one of these the whole application closes...

So what I whant as a result is that the specific user control closes but the project doesn't.

Comment: You need to get the instance of the User control and then use the close statement with that.

Comment: There is no concept such as "closing user control". You can only close window. Or remove control from container. You can use `ContentControl`, which `Content` is set to `new UserControl()` when you want to show it and to `null` when you want to hide it. Another option to control `Visibility` of user control.

Comment: Can you post the code you use to display your control please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Popup to show usercontrol

```
Popup p = new Popup();
YourUserControl yuc = new YourUserControl();
p.Child = yuc;
p.IsOpen = true;
```

and you can close it using

```
p.IsOpen=false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a popup control for that.

```
    <CheckBox Name="CheckBoxIsOpen"  Content="IsOpen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Popup Name="myPopup" Width="300" Height="100" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=CheckBoxIsOpen}" VerticalOffset="10" IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=CheckBoxIsOpen, Path=IsChecked}">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="LightGray">
            <TextBlock Text="This is the content of my popup."/>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
```

Then you can show or hide the popup by setting the IsOpen property.

```
myPopup.IsOpen = true;
```